# Flutter Plugin project :sign_in_apple not found. Please update settings.gradle

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, apple-sign-in

Facing this issue when building the flutter project in Android 31.

**ERROR:**

```
Plugin project :sign_in_apple not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/myusername/fluttersdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 421

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just replace this code into the
**android>>settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the steps for adding Apple SignIn to android.
https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple

Comment: Actually the issues comes for android build, it is working fine with iOS build.. this is not the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have run into a similar issue and although the suggestion above works (manually changing the gradle rule to look for the `.flutter-plugins` file) this should be handled by the default `android/settings.gradle` file.

The root cause for me turned out to be that the plugin's `pubspec.yaml` didn't have a

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:  # <-- was missing
        ...
```

entry. This in return caused it not to show up in `android` plugins of the `.flutter-plugins-dependencies` file, which in turn made the flutter gradle rules not pick up the dependency

(The `.flutter-plugins` file is deprecated in favor of `.flutter-plugins-dependencies`).